# Getting list of Soundcloud user likes with ios sdk

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am trying to build an application where users can share their soundcloud likes with eachother. I have the sdk installed to the point of logging in and being able to retrieve a list of tracks uploaded by the user but how do i get a list of the songs that a user has liked? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to take a look on the docs?

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me

The endpoint is:

- /me/favorites OR
- /users/{id}/favorites